# Read from perl text box

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to read a value jj from the perl text box

```
    print $q->textfield(
       -name => 'UserName',
       -value =>'jj',
       -size  => 15,
       -maxlength =>40,
    );
```

I Used to read

```
     my $txt=$q->param('UserName');
```

but its not read from the Textbox.

Comment: Are you running the first script, getting a form in the browser, then submitting that form to the second script?

Comment: No now i just default define the value in the text box  same page i am tried to get that

Answer (score 0):

`param` will give you data submitted via POST or the query string to the CGI program. It will not give you data that is going to appear in a form you outputted earlier in the script.

If you want to know that, then put the data in a variable before you start using it.

```
my $txt = "jj";

print $q->textfield(
   -name => 'UserName',
   -value => $txt,
   -size  => 15,
   -maxlength =>40,
);
```

Comment: how can i get the run time value like when executing the script in the web browser that time i enter the email id in the text box, that email id i want to read when the button is pressed.

Comment: That is when you use `param`.

Comment: here is the button i used how can read when button is clicked
print $q->submit(
 -name => 'submit',
 -value => 'Login',
);